# Possible to have a web.config in APP_DATA merged with the original in the root?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i would like to have my main web.config in the root where it normally is and have another merged in.

Is this possible , i was thinking on placing a another web.config in APP_DATA/CONFIG which will have some additonal stuff that i can update without having to touch the main web.config

I seem to remember that this is possible but i am unsure..  can asp.net dynamically merge these and use both??

Can anyone provide further info?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you mean by *merge* web.config files, but you can have web.config files in subfolders of your ASP.NET application which could override some sections from the root config file (only some sections could be overridden). So for example you could have the following section in your root web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
</appSettings>
```

and then have a ~/somefolder/web.config which overrides this section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="baz" />
</appSettings>
```

and now if inside `~/somefolder/foo.aspx` you try to access `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]` you would get `baz`.

Comment: Thanks Darin, yes this i am aware of, but placing the web.config in APP_DATA/config works also?  Its not i want to override an additional folder.  I have a sample website here i am looking at and it does indeed have a web.config under APP_DATA/config and it appears to work and i wanted to the do the same but i don't fully understand this... It is like asp.net is taking web.config from the route but also taking or merging what is in APP_DATA/config/web.config

Comment: @Martin, why do you need a web.config file inside the App_Data folder? What's its purpose? The App_Data folder is supposed to contain only database/data files, not code. And it is only code that makes sense of web.config files. So your requirement seems pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file=` param of the `<appSettings>` block, if it is only things in there that you need to override.

in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="relative_path_to_other.config">
        <add key="foo" value="bar" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and in your other config file you just define the `<appSettings>` section (*not* the whole config file)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="baz" />
</appSettings>
```